# How to reverse both axes in ContourPlot?

Tags: plotting, functions

How to reverse X and Y axis in `ContourPlot`? I tried to do this many times and always I reversed just one axes, the other one didn't change. The X axis is correct but Y is incorrect. I want the values on the Y axis to be greater than 0. Is it possible? 
I used `ContourPlot` because I have functions like $F(x,y)=x^2+y^2$
[image: contour plot]

Comment: Does `ContourPlot[x^3 - y^2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", "Reverse"}]` not do what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As J.M. pointed out, `ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -50, 0}, ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", "Reverse"}]` will reverse both axes.  If you'd only like one axis reversed, you can replace one of those `"Reverse"`s with `Automatic`.

Comment: Thank you!! It was so easy :) A used just one "Reverse" i thats why it didnt work.

Comment: You can also use more generic `Automatic` instead of `Identity` (which is specific to this task), as usual with most such lists as values of options.

Comment: `Automatic` is better I've changed it to say that